# Input value doesn't change after PHP script is added

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

Without the PHP script the value of the email address would automatically  change after the studo number, functie and onderwijsinst values are entered, but as soon as I added the PHP script, the email value doesn't change anymore. The emailaddress needs to be automatically generated as shown in the jQuery code.

HTML code

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-12">
                  <div class="form-group has-feedback" id="num">
                    <input type="text" required pattern="[a-z]{1}[0-9]{7}" name="studo_number" id="studo_number" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Student/docent nummer" tabindex="4" maxlength="8" title="Nummer moet beginnen met 1 kleine letter en 7 cijfers">
                  </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback" id="fun">
                        <select class="form-control input-lg" name="functie" id="functie" required>
                            <option value="" disabled selected>Functie</option>
                            <option value="student">Student</option>
                            <option value="docent">Docent</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback" id="ond">
                    <select class="form-control input-lg" name="onderwijsinst" id="onderwijsinst" required>
                            <option value="" disabled selected>Onderwijsinstelling</option>
                            <option value="thomas more">Thomas More</option>
                            <option value="hik">CVO</option>
                        </select>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="E-mailadres" tabindex="5" disabled required>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

jQuery code (this was the quickest solution I could come up with)

```
jQuery(function (){

    setInterval(function() {

    var $studo_input = $("#studo_number").val();
    var $functie_input = $("#functie").val();
    var $onderw_input = $("#onderwijsinst").val();
    var $hik = "hik.be";
    var $tm = "thomasmore.be";
    var $student = "student.";

    if($studo_input !== "" && $functie_input !== "" && $onderw_input !== ""){
        if($functie_input === "student"){
            if($onderw_input === "hik"){
                $("#email").val($studo_input + "@" + $hik);
            }
            else if ($onderw_input === "tm"){
                $("#email").val($studo_input + "@" + $student + $tm);
            }
        }
        else if($functie_input === "docent"){
            if($onderw_input === "hik"){
                $("#email").val($studo_input + "@" + $hik);
            }
            else if($onderw_input === "tm"){
                $("#email").val($studo_input + "@" + $tm);
            }
        }
    }
    else if($studo_input === "" || $functie_input === "" || $onderw_input === ""){


    }
    },500);
});
```

PHP code

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "mail@mail.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $sur = $_POST['surname'];
    $lname = $_POST['last_name'];
    $username = $_POST['display_name'];
    $studonr = $_POST['studo_number'];
    $funct = $_POST['functie'];
    $onderw = $_POST['onderwijsinst'];
    $voorw = $_POST['t_and_c'];
    $subject = "Registratie aanvraag";
    $subject2 = "Kopie van je registratie aanvraag";
    $message = "GEBRUIKERSNAAM: " . $username . "\n" . "VOORNAAM: " . $sur . "\n" . "ACHTERNAAM: " . $lname . "\n" . "STUDENT/DOCENT NUMMER: " . $studonr . "\n" . "FUNCTIE: " . $funct . "\n" . "ONDERWIJSINSTELLING: " . $onderw . "\n" . "EMAIL ADRES: " . $from . "\n" . "GAAT AKKOORT MET DE ALGEMENE VOORWAARDEN & HET HUISHOUDELIJK REGLEMENT: " . $voorw ;
    $message2 = "Hier is een kopie van je gegevens: \n\n" . "GEBRUIKERSNAAM: " . $username . "\n" . "VOORNAAM: " . $sur . "\n" . "ACHTERNAAM: " . $lname . "\n" . "STUDENT/DOCENT NUMMER: " . $studonr . "\n" . "FUNCTIE: " . $funct . "\n" . "ONDERWIJSINSTELLING: " . $onderw . "\n" . "EMAIL ADRES: " . $from . "\n" . "GAAT AKKOORT MET DE ALGEMENE VOORWAARDEN & HET HUISHOUDELIJK REGLEMENT: " . $voorw ;

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $sur . ", we will contact you shortly.";
    // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
    }
?>
```

Comment: missing quite a few parts of the form and there's no way for us to know whether or not `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){...}` even fires, and/or any of the other inputs contain values. When in doubt; error reporting and look at your console.

Comment: the code works, if I submit all the values are send to my email, except the email, since it is not filled in... and the console doesn't show any errors

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it; I had to change `$("#email").val($studo_input + "@" + $tm);` to `$("#email").val($studo_input + "@" + $thomas more);` I forgot I changed that option.